# Web components (JavaScript native) naming limitations?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I know that Web components naming has below limitations:

- Capital alphabet symbols is not allowed.
- Must include at least one n-dash.

Any others? What about underscore, digits and other symbols?

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#valid-custom-element-name

Comment: @xdeepakv, Because it's unobvious that naming rules are odd with html tags naming rules (except n-dash requirement) for developers who just started learning the web components.

Comment: Google some of the basic expectations/docs developers already provide. Stackoverflow for bad part of code. Not good Part:-D

Comment: @xdeepakv Well, links are welcome. Although my question has been down-voted, maybe it will  appear  in Google's SERP and development who finds the answer to same question will be directed to documentation via answers and comments.

Comment: Its true, but too much info can miss guide too. Data is good analytics, but not in all cases. hahaha! cheers. happy coding!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': "299742-nowjedi-hello" is not a valid custom element name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60667115/syntaxerror-failed-to-execute-define-on-customelementregistry-299742-nowj)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Yes. But this question's title is not optimized for search request "Web component name rules". Also, tag "React" is off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the full specification from the HTML spec:

A valid custom element name is a sequence of characters name that meets all of the following requirements:

> name must match the PotentialCustomElementName production:
>
> ```
> PotentialCustomElementName ::=
>    [a-z] (PCENChar)* '-' (PCENChar)*
> PCENChar ::=
>    "-" | "." | [0-9] | "_" | [a-z] | #xB7 | [#xC0-#xD6] | 
>    [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | 
>    [#x203F-#x2040] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] |
>    [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | 
>    [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
> ```
>
> This uses the EBNF notation from the XML specification. [XML]
>
> name must not be any of the following:
>
> ```
>    annotation-xml
>    color-profile
>    font-face
>    font-face-src
>    font-face-uri
>    font-face-format
>    font-face-name
>    missing-glyph
> ```

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#valid-custom-element-name

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I don't know why it has been down-voted, by I will upvote.